# How to configure spring security with custom JAAS stack?

Tags: spring-security, jaas

I have followed [this tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html) in order to add basic spring security to my spring mvcbasedweb app.

Before adding the spring security layer my app was protected using acustom SSO login module configured in my web.xml:

```
 <login-config>
        <auth-method>MyLoginModule</auth-method>
    </login-config>
```

This login module takescare of redirecting to the login form, performing login etc. and isworking asexpected. 
After adding the basic spring security layer the app is redirecting to my custom login page and when I authenticate pass me through yet another authentication using spring's standard "Login with Username and Password" form.

My question is how to configure spring to only use my login-config above to perform the authentication and remove it's redundant own "built in" form?

Comment: Did you read the information on JAAS in the reference manual, look at the JAAS sample and so on? Also it might make sense to mention JAAS in your question title since the term "login module" is pretty vague by itself and many people won't realise you're referring to a specific technology.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the question tagging. Not sure I understand your question. My JAAS stack works fine on its own, my spring security setup works fine on its own, I just can't seem to make spring security to fire MyLoginModule to do the authentication stuff.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in the Spring Security reference. Specifically, the chapter on [Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) Provider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jaas.html).

Comment: This url will always point to the current version of Spring Security:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jaas.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I haven't understood your scenario before. Check [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring-security-and-wicket-auth-roles.html) to perform your authentication. You should register the user into the SecurityContextHolder.

Also visit the [oficial spring 3.1 security reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic).

The following example is for typical form web authentication (be sure to identify it with spring j_username/password):

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm"
action="<c:url value='my_security_check'/>" method="POST">
    ... 
<label for="user">The username</label><input type="text" name="j_username"/>
<label for="password">The password</label><input type='password'
      name='j_password'/>
    ...
<input name="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit"/>
    ...
```

You have to define this security check in your spring security file:

```
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        login-processing-url="/my_security_check" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/my_security_logout"
        logout-success-url="/login" />
 </security:http>
```

In my case I'm using Tiles i have to also add this to my mvc config file :

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login" />
```

Example and source code : mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

Comment: but this is to tell it where my login page is, I want it to use my LoginModule which in turns redirects the user to the login page

Comment: just define your default-target-url to the page you want in spring security. I edit the answer to be more concise.

Comment: again, there is no login page I can setup, there is a login module configured in my jass stack that takes care of it and I want spring security to invoke/use it in order to perform the login

Comment: If you don't use spring for login, try to get the autenticated user , or set it with spring.     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();